# Is this website setting us up to be put out of the job by AI?

Tags: discussion

Has there been any pushback from the community here about text from Stack Overflow being used to train AI language models that can write code?

By posting and answering questions here, we're essentially assembling training data for AI that has the potential to put many of people who write code out of work.

Is this even being considered as an issue?

Comment: If an AI can solve all of the problems brought forward to SO, mission accomplished.

Comment: I think it takes *a whole lot more* to be a software developer than writing small snippets of code.

Comment: I would not want to use software written by a bot that learned to code only from Stack Overflow

Comment: By solving recaptcha, you're most likely helping put bus and taxi drivers out of a job long-term. Progress means some things become redundant. Welcome to the universe. Hundreds or even thousands or more occupations have historically existed and then ceased to exist due to advances in tech. It's how society works. However, when jobs cease to exist, new ones are made. That assumes programming as a job is likely to be erased in the near future, which it won't be. But hey, feel free not to contribute if you're concerned. No one's forcing you to contribute

Comment: there is no way that ea learning software can do that and if you manage it feel free to piblish, i would like to see the result. but most machine learning is that what epert system was some 20 years ago, all system are in its infancy and don't seem to make much progress. So go ahead,please

Comment: [Garbage in, garbage out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) still applies, AI or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's only an issue if you think AI could realistically perform your job duties.

To the point of using the data from Stack Overflow - I mean, GitHub's tool [already pulls from its vast expanse of repos, <s>private and</s> public](https://github.com/features/copilot), [proprietary and open-source](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/github-copilot-ai-code-creation-ip-violation-ankit-sharma), so it's a bit of a moot point if someone points an AI at Stack Overflow and trains it on this data, too.

It would mean that the AI is pretty unusable, but who knows when someone'd actually find that out...

Comment: Worth noting that copilot's #1 feature is its code plagiarism feature, where it takes code verbatim, including comments, from repos under an incompatible license (primarily copyleft IIRC).

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine:  Sounds like it wouldn't make a whole lot of difference if it *did* train on Stack Overflow anwyay.  I mean, people here do that *anyway*, just without the fancy AI.